# Bootstrap dropdown's do not render correctly on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5.2

When I view my project on a desktop all the dropdowns are aligned and flush which looks really nice, when I minimize the browser to view on a mobile this is what it looks like,

[image]

As you can see all the dropdowns are difference sizes, I'm not sure how this happened? I'm aware it takes into considering the content you have in each i.e how long each word is but is there a safe way within bootstrap I can achieve a fixed width for all dropdowns wether its being viewed on a mobile/tablet or desktop? this is my current markup for the above picture

```
 <div class="row col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Country</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8 input-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserDetails.SelectedCountry, Model.UserDetails.ListCountries, "Please Select Country", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "javascript:this.form.submit();" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8 input-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserDetails.SelectedState, Model.UserDetails.ListStates, new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "javascript:this.form.submit();" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">City</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8 input-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserDetails.SelectedCity, Model.UserDetails.ListCities, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Postcode</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8 input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserDetails.Postcode, new { @class = "form-control", Placeholder = "Your Postcode", maxlength = "12" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link with css?

Comment: Are you using custom CSS or it this pure Bootstrap?

Comment: @FloatingRock pure bootstrap.

Comment: @Nima I'm at work at the moment, ill be able to upload the style sheet tonight and reference you it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work since according to the [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example), any control with the `.form-control` class should have `width:100%` by default.

I noticed an issue with your class assignments for the rows though. It should look like so:

```
<div class="row">
  ...
</div>
```

and **NOT**:

```
<div class="row col-lg-12">
  ...
</div>
```

Let me know if that helps!